# Excel for Mac Version 16.18 is dividing my numbers by 10

Tags: microsoft-excel, macbook

Excel has just started dividing my entries by 10.  If i type '2' in a cell it writes 0.2 and so on. I have no idea what i changed that caused this to start but would love some help to fix this?

Comment: does re-install excel helps?

Answer (score 0):

In Excel for Windows there is an Advanced setting in Options to Automatically insert a decimal point with a defined number of decimal places - usually 2 but could be changed to 1.
[image: Auto decimal input option]

Uncheck this box and you should be back to "Normal".